# how to create a tf.layers.Dense object

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create a dense layer in tensorflow. I tried `tf.layers.dense(input_placeholder, units)` which will directly create this layer and get result, but what I want is just a "layer module", i.e. an object of the class `tf.layers.Dense(units)`. I want to first declare these modules/layers in a class, and then to have several member functions `apply1(x, y)`, `apply2(x,y)` to use these layers.
But when I did in tensorflow `tf.layers.Dense(units)`, it returned:

> layer = tf.layers.Dense(100) AttributeError: 'module' object has no
>   attribute 'Dense'

But if I do `tf.layers.dense(x, units)`, there's no problem.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`tf.layers.Dense` returns a function object that you later apply to your input. It performs variable definitions.

```
func = tf.layers.Dense(out_dim)
out = func(inputs)
```

`tf.layers.dense` performs both variable definitions and application of the dense layer to your input to calculate your output.

```
out = tf.layers.dense(inputs, out_dim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the usage of placeholders, you have to feed_dict into the tf.Session so its probably causing this issue.

Try to use the new estimator api to load the data and then use dense layers as is done in the tensorflow's github examoples: [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py]:

Comment: The link you provided is not working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.layers.Dense` was not exported in TensorFlow before version 1.4. You probably have version 1.3 or earlier installed. (You can check the version with `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'`.)